# Nest not giving desired results

Tags: recursion, numerical-value, iteration

I am trying to use `Nest` to find result using fixed point iteration method, but when I find $g(x)$ and put it in `Nest`, it doesn't gives me the desired result.

```
expr = x^3 + x^2 - 1
gx = generateG[expr]  

result = Nest[(gx &, 0.5, 10]
(* value of result after 10 iterations *)
```

> ```
> 1 - x^2)^(1/3)
> ```

What I want is:

```
result = Nest[(1 - #^2)^(1/3) &, 0.5, 10]
(* value after 10 iterations *)
```

> ```
> 0.686642
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```
expr = x^3 + x^2 - 1;
```

You have not provided the definition of `generateG`

The value after 10 iterations is not a good estimate of the fixed point.

```
(data = NestList[(1 - #^2)^(1/3) &, 0.5`15, 50])[[11]] // N

(* 0.686642 *)
```

The fixed point is

```
fp = FixedPoint[(1 - #^2)^(1/3) &, 0.5`15, 
   SameTest -> (Abs[#1 - #2] < 1*^-15 &)] // N

(* 0.754878 *)

ListPlot[data,
 Epilog -> {Red, Line[{{0, fp}, {50, fp}}]}]
```

[image]

The fixed point is equal to the positive root

```
fp == x /. Solve[{expr == 0, x > 0}, x][[1]]

(* True *)
```